# Dynamic font size readjustment to the layout

Tags: ios, swift

I've been fighting these last two days trying to figure out how to change the font size to adjust for the available space.

As you see in the image I'm working on, the header of my table has two problems.

First I'm unable to change the header properties to set for instance the adjustsFontSizeToFitWith property because I create the outlet on the UITableViewCell but I'm unable to access the label.

When I do cell.lblCurrentTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true I get the error
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
also doesn't make much sense to do this inside cellForRowAt method.

Second setting the "Automatically adjust font" on the storyboard doesnt seems to fit the words to the available space. I also get this warning "automatically adjusts font requires using a Dynamic Type text Style" what does this means? I tried several combinations of adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and numberOfLines = 0 or 1 and I haven't been able to make it fit to use 2 lines with adjusted width.

What do I have to do in order to make the words fit in 2 lines with adjusted font size to fit all the words?

[image]

Comment: use word wrap, not character wrap, and set numberOfLines = 2, and set minimumFontScale

Comment: numberodlines = 2, and yourLabel.sizeThatFit

Comment: im already using number of lines 2 and word wrap, i know it looks weird but that screenshot is already the result with theses changes

Comment: @JoãoSerra how can you be using word warp if the word "result" is cut in half?

Comment: @YoCoh i wish i knew but i swear im using it. I've also tried setting the autoshrink to Minimum Font Size = 5

Comment: @JoãoSerra by the way, storyboard can act strange sometimes and use cached values ... just to be sure, clean the project and run again.

Comment: just an update, the clean project didnt help. The font size is only readjusted if numberOfLine is set to 1

Comment: So until find a better solution I've divided each label into several labels, each one uses 1 line, this way i can use "automatically adjusts font"